# Accessing python class member inside methods

Tags: class, python-2.7

This is my code

```
class Mine:
    def __init__(self):
        var = "Hello"
    def mfx(self):
        var += "a method is called"
        print var

    me = Mine()
```

when i call`me.mfx()` it gives the following error

```
>>> me.mfx()

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#1>", line 1, in <module>
    me.mfx()
  File "D:\More\Pythonnnn\text.py", line 5, in mfx
    var += "a method is called"
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'var' referenced before assignment
>>>
```

I need var only to use inside the class.
So i don't want self.var . Why is this happening?
How can I make a variable which can be used everywhere inside the class.
I am using Python2.7

Answer (score 0):

You should qualify var. (`self.var` instead of `var`)

```
class Mine:
    def __init__(self):
        self.var = "Hello"
    def mfx(self):
        self.var += "a method is called"
        print self.var

me = Mine()
me.mfx()
```

Answer (score 0):

You *must* use `self`, otherwise you create a local variable that is only accessible inside the method it is created in.

Comment: I wish if i could create a variable which can be accessed by all methods in the class. So if we want a variable which is accessible across methods we need 'self.' prefix

Comment: That's what binding it to `self` does.

Comment: or we can write `global var` in all method declarations

Answer (score 0):

you need to use self to access an instance variable. It's also better to use new style classes and also passed in parameter for your constructor

```
class Mine(object):
    def __init__(self, var):
        self.var = var

    def mfx(self):
        self.var += "a method is called"
        print self.var

me = Mine()
me.mfx()
```

if you don't want to passed "hello" everytime, just create a default value

```
def __init__(self, var="hello"):
      self.var = var
```